# How to concatenate string in ROOT,c++?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, root-framework

I want to concatenate two string and I did in my program like `String Filename = name+ "" + extension` where extension is an integer value that I read just above this line and name is the path that is already defined.

But in ROOT I am getting error like `Error: + illegal operator for pointer 1`

What went wrong here? Is there any other method?

Comment: If this is C++/CLI, you need to always use `^` with reference types: `String^ Filename = ...` (but you don't tell us what `name` or `extension` are, so there might be problems there too).

Answer (score 1):

If `extension` is an integer, then convert it to a string first.

```
std::string Filename = name+ "" + std::to_string(extension);
```

`+""+` does nothing, btw

Comment: what is `name`? Did you remove `+""+` and still get the error?

Comment: In .h file, I defined name as<br/> 
    '#define name "A:\\Project\\event_"'

In .C file I defined extension as<br/> 
    string FILENAME;<br/>
    string extension;<br/>
    cout<”enter the file number”;
    cin>> extension;<br/>
    Filename=name+  ”” + extension;<br/>

And I expect to get my file name as<br/> 'A:\\Project\\event_1'

Comment: Ok, so extension is a `string` and not an integer as you stated. `name` is a character array, so cannot be added to another, `""`. Remove `+""+` as I said, and then you'll have `std::string Filename = name + extension;` and that'll work. Your code needs a lot of other changes, outside of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The TString class in ROOT has a function called "Format" which you can use to concatenate strings the same way you format a print statement. Here is the documentation for the Format method: https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TString.html#TString:Format

and here is the documentation for how the formatting works http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and assume the 'name' is a char*.

```
Char const*  name = "john";
Char const* space = " ";
```

Here name and space are 2 pointers to character arrays.

When you add try to add these 2 together, the compiler tries to add the value of the 2 pointer together. This makes no sense to the compiler. You can obviously only add an offset to a pointer.

The solution to this is to make sure that one of the 2 things you are adding is a std::string and not 'c string'.